# ASP Classic Dictionary [Key, Array] Error

Tags: arrays, dictionary, asp-classic

I have a function that uploads an Excel file to my server and saves this file in a dictionary[Key, Array].

I loop the rows of the Excel file, create an array with the values of that row and add this array to the dictionary like that:

```
Set excel = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
excel.Open sql, conn

Set newExcel = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
i = 0

Do Until excel.EOF
   newRow = Array(excel(0), excel(1), excel(2), excel(3), excel(4), excel(5), excel(6), excel(7))
   newExcel.Add i, newRow

   i = i + 1
   excel.MoveNext
Loop
```

And then I try to access the filled dictionary to print the values but I get an error on the `Response.Write row(j)`.

```
For Each k In newExcel.Keys
   row = newExcel.Item(k)

   For j = LBound(row) To UBound(row)
      Response.Write row(j)
   Next
Next
```

The error:

```
ADODB.Field error '80020009'

Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: It's because you are trying to store the [`ADODB.Field` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/field-object?view=sql-server-ver16) inside the array but it is connected to an `ADODB.Recordset` which requires an active database connection. Instead just store the values, i.e `Array(excel(0).Value, etc... `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are copying the `ADODB.Field` objects not their underlying values. This means when you access the array it tries to access the `ADODB.Field` object which requires an active database connection. If you have since closed the database connection you will receive the error;

> ADODB.Field error '80020009'
>
> Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

Adjusting this line

```vb
newRow = Array(excel(0), excel(1), excel(2), excel(3), excel(4), excel(5), excel(6), excel(7))
```

to

```vb
newRow = Array(excel(0).Value, excel(1).Value, excel(2).Value, excel(3).Value, excel(4).Value, excel(5).Value, excel(6).Value, excel(7).Value)
```

will store the underlying values, not the objects themselves.